# Create react native custom header style?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, mobile-development

I am new for react native development. I need to create custom header for both IOS/Android platforms using react native. Because this header bottom edge have rounded corners. please refer the given image. [image]

Comment: where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would recommend posting some of your code, so we could get an idea of what you've tried to do so far.

Secondly, if your problem is making the bottom corners rounded like in the picture, you might use these properties in the style of your View:

- borderBottomLeftRadius
- borderBottomRightRadius

Similar situation for top corners, where you can use these two properties in order to round them:

- borderTopLeftRadius
- borderTopRightRadius

Finally, if you need to round them all, you can simply use this property instead of writing all of the above:

- borderRadius